# PostgreSQL 9.5 doesn't start after reboot with systemd

Tags: linux, database, postgresql, ubuntu-16.04, systemd

I'm having a problem with PostgreSQL 9.5+173 on Ubuntu 16.04 and I happened to stumble across the following threads in my research that somewhat describes the behavior I'm seeing:

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAFyxdeT%2B%3Dx-d0oNbFPoe%2B4xnt0Qdfi%2BzAEn%2BrQmEK0AZbJFRtg%40mail.gmail.com

https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/562E4453.5090803%40aklaver.com

Long story short I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 16 with nothing on it and PostgreSQL running. I've stopped PostgreSQL changed the data directory and port and a couple other settings and it starts back up fine.

I can start and stop PostgreSQL manually via `systemctl` without any problems. I can also connect to the database and can verify that it is running via a `ps ax | grep postgres`.

However, after I reboot PostgreSQL will not start up. Any attempt to start it up via `systemctl start postgresql.service` doesn't do anything and does not fail. The only way I am able to get it started is if I call `systemctl start postgresql@9.5-main.service`.

I did some investigation and looked at both the **postgresql.service** and **postgresql@9.5-main.service** scripts and realized that the postgresql.service script does nothing as stated in the thread above and that the postgresql@9.5-main.service has the PartOf directive which means it should be getting triggered from the postgresql.service as the sytemd docs state, but it isn't for some reason. Basically I'm at a loss as to why everything works before I reboot and then doesn't work after I reboot. Is there something I'm missing? I'm starting to go **CRAZY** over something so simple.

**Update:** I added an `ExecStartPre=/bin/touch /tmp/postgresq.log` to the **postgresql@9.5-main.service** to see if it's actually getting called on boot and it is not. Manually calling `systemctl start postgresql@9.5-main.service` creates the file in the /tmp directory.

**Update:** I have also found that calling `systemd daemon-reload` after reboot will allow me to start postgres via the `systemctl start postgresql` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the problem was the fact that I symlinked `/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/` across partitions to a custom partition that wasn't available right away, so when PostgreSQL tried to start on boot it couldn't because it's configuration files were not available. This describes what was happening since I could start PostgreSQL manually after I logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try doing systemctl enable postgresql? This will tell systemd to start this service after boot. Try rebooting after that.

Comment: Yes postgresql was enabled via `systemctl enable postgresql`